# Copy inner HTML of a banner to my div

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Hi iam using an iframe for a banner and I have a tabbed div that will load data through $.get on each tab clicking,and thorough $.get method can we get the banner script and load it on my page through $.get method

I written get like on each click on tab

```
$.get("/index.php", { 'ext': "myvotingpics",'action' : "Show" },
            function(response) {                                
                data = response;                                       
            });
```

and iam appending data to my main page div...

```
 $('#My_div").html(data);
```

.but after clicking on any tab it displaying blank screen....if I remove banner script it will working fine....So my question is how to load script on my page through $.get method **EACH** time

Comment: "and i am appending data to my main page div" is something we cannot see. Additionally I would try logging out the response.

Comment: if it is only script you can load it via [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: Nope it has both html and script also

Answer (score 0):

Its not appending, its replacing. But thats fine as long as the text in data is valid html.

But in your case it is a script. So it should be `<script>'yourDataHere'</script>`

But I would recommend you use `$.getScript` to load and run a script:

```
$.getScript("test.js", function(){
    alert("Running test.js");
});
```